# Error during WebSocket handshake: Status line contains embedded null (using livereload, node-inspector, and karma)

Tags: terminal, safari, homebrew

Whenever I run something in my Terminal that requires a websocket to a browser (livereload, node-inspector, karma), I get the following console error "Error during WebSocket handshake: Status line contains embedded null." Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like my iMac at home is able to pass all of the tests except for Port 80 on websocketstest.com (http://websocketstest.com/result/326808) but the laptop which is having the problem fails on port 80, 443, and 8080 (http://websocketstest.com/result/326811)

Answer (score 1):

Lame, looks like it was my accountability software x3watch.